# Getting the problem java.lang.AssertionError while trying to add assert profilePicUrl != null;

Tags: java, android-studio

**Code:**

```java
assert profilePicUrl !=null;
if(!profilePicUrl.isEmpty()){
    // set profile pic to circle image view
    Picasso.get().load(profilePicUrl).into(userProfilePic);
}
```

**Error:**

```
java.lang.AssertionError
        at com.nsstudio.monkeychat.MainActivity$1.onDataChange(MainActivity.java:58)
        at com.google.firebase.database.Query$1.onDataChange(Query.java:191)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:75)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:63)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:55)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

The code `assert profilePicUrl !=null;` is the 58th line of the whole code.
Now I need solution how I can Solve it.

Comment: You need to find why profilePicUrl is null. What part of your code is supposed to set its value?

Comment: @SameerNaik Actually, I am new in Android Studio and I am trying to find the why this is null. I am making this app with the help of a YouTube Tutorial. Thanks though...

Comment: Please check your source code and see where profilePicUrl is getting assigned a value. or share you code here.

Comment: @SameerNaik I actually solved it by clicking Alt + Enter. Thanks BTW.